# What size aluminum foil capacitor would power an LED?

Tags: electricity, capacitance, light-emitting-diodes

Inspired by [this video where a $9 \mu F$ capacitor is made from aluminum foil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uC7HN9oFpZ0), if I had students put this together in a classroom, one question I would have is what would it take to have this power an LED? (Ideally we would be able to make a capacitor that could power one in class.)  Using [this](http://www.ledsupply.com/leds/5mm-led-white-15-degree-viewing-angle?gclid=Cj0KEQjwgLGuBRCqptLsnJCvh-wBEiQAiNRjsTNzGQ3Gg1PJPiVPWWehz6RgRbtU5D2klks9GR0WfoMaAmYR8P8HAQ) LED as an example, it requires 3.2 forward voltage and 20 mA. How would I relate that to the capacitor and its capacitance?